How to extract a part of a line that is between two specific strings using a batch script
I am trying to extract strings which are between <meta property="al:ios:url" content="snssdk1180://live?room_id= and " data-rh="true">.
Example Input:
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="snssdk1180://live?room_id=7362593220718381829" data-rh="true">

Expected Output:
7362593220718381829


Is batch a must? Because it is so much easier to do in PowerShell.

Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Is there more than 1 room_id on each text file?

Something like this:
@echo off

set TextFile=test.txt

for /f tokens^=^5^ delims^=^=^" %%a in ('type "%TextFile%" ^|find /i "live?room_id"') do set "Output=%%a"

echo %Output%
echo.
pause
exit

